# Remove value from List of Map in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary

Remove value from list in java containing map

I am having list in this form:

```
List: [{id=1,c_id=3,value=5},{id=1,c_id=2,value=5},{id=1,c_id=3,value=5},{id=2,c_id=1,value=5},       
        {id=2,c_id=null,value=5}}];
```

In result I am trying to get

```
List: [{id=1,c_id=3,value=5},,{id=1,c_id=2,value=5},{id=2,c_id=1,value=5}}]
```

For same `id` if `c_id` is same it should be removed and also if `c_id` is `null` it should be removed.

Comment: It is the output of the debugger.

Comment: I assume you don't want the `,,`

Comment: Why does it remove the second `c_id=3` but not the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
for(Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Map<String, Object> map = iter.next();
    Object c_id = map.get("c_id");
    if (c_id == null || c_id.equals(matching_c_id))
        iter.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Guava solution](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#removeIf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29):

```
Iterables.removeIf(list, new Predicate<Element>(){
    @Override public boolean apply(Element e) {
        return e.c_id == null || e.c_id.equals(matching_c_id);
}});
```

Comment: You could also add the Java 8 version (as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30654594/276052)).

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution could be the following one and I think it is readable.

First, construct a set element proxy for your object type:

```
public class MyTypeProxy {

     private MyType obj;

     public MyTypeProxy(MyType obj) {

         this.obj = obj;

     }

     public MyType getObj() { return this.obj; }

     public int hashcode() {

         return obj.getC_id() ^ obj.getId();

     }

     public boolean equals(Object ref) {

         if (ref.getClass() != MyTypeProxy.class) {
             return false;
         }
         return 
              ((MyTypeProxy)ref).obj.getC_id() == this.obj.getC_id() &&
              ((MyTypeProxy)ref).obj.getId() == this.obj.getC_id();
     }
}
```

Then, in your code, you can construct a HashSet.

```
HashSet<MyTypeProxy> set = new HashSet<MyTypeProxy>();

for (MyType mt : list) {
    if (mt.getC_id() != null){
        set.add(new MyTypeProxy(myList));
    }
}
```

The following does two things. First, it excludes objects with a null c_id field and second, it filters out objects with the same id and c_id combination. You might want to consider if keeping the first one is ok or not (that is what the above code does).

The set now contains exactly what you need.