# Java removing elements from List of maps

Tags: java, arrays

I have Java `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>`. Is it okay to remove elements from that list as follows:

```
    for (Map<String, Object> anObject : manyObjects) {
        if (anObject.get("x").equals("y")) {
            manyObjects.remove(anObject);
        }
    }
```

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with this approach?

Comment: don't see any issues. Are you experiencing any problems or just looking for maybe a better way to accomplish your goals?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583770/remove-value-from-list-of-map-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't removes elements from a List while iterating over it with the enhanced for loop, since it will throw a CuncurrentModificationException. You can use an explicit iterator instead :

```
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iter = manyObjects.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, Object> anObject = iter.next();
    if (anObject.get("x").equals("y")) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't make structural modifications to the list (such as removing elements from it) while iterating over it using an enhanced for loop. That would (most likely) end up in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Here's a better way using the stream API:

```
manyObjects.removeIf(map -> map.get("x").equals("y"));
```

The "old" (pre Java 8) way is to use an iterator and the `remove()` method as follows:

```
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iter = manyObjects.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next().get("x").equals("y"))
        iter.remove();
}
```